# when clicking the submit button twice the path to the methos is changed

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a form that is something like this:

```
   <form class="float_left" method="post" action="Home/Start">
   ....
   <input type="submit" value="start"/>
   </form>
```

When I click on the submit button I will land in the HomeController.Start() method, that performs some things and then it calls again the View (the view is Index.cshtml). Something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Start(ModelClass model)
    {
        //here I do things

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

The first time I click the button everything goes like I expect, but if I click again the button, it will try to reach Home/Home/Start instead of Home/Start. Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When formatted like you have it (`"Home/Start"`) it is relative to the current page, so it can change the URL depending on where you are.

Instead you should use `Url.Action` like so:

```
<form class="float_left" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Start", "Home")">
```

This will create an absolute URL, which will always work the same, regardless of what the current URL is.

There are also other `HtmlHelpers` that you should check out. [This blog post by Michael Kennedy is an excellent tutorial.](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/)